# Powershell - Auto Login of Win 7 Desktop

Tags: powershell, windows-7

I am looking to automate a solution that will allow me to auto log into a win7 desktop from PowerShell in order to start a number of other cmds around performance testing.  I.e Log into desktop, start some application and start the perform data collectors etc using logman.exe.

I have the second part of this completed but am stumped with the login part.  Due to a stringent security policy I am unable to run PowerShell on remote machines even though I'm a member of the admin group on each machine it appears.

I was looking at using the below in order to login, but when I login it brings me up the corporate security policy that  I need to press ok to accept.  Is there any way I can do this in PowerShell, is anyone able to tell me how I can press the ok/accept button when logging in?

```
cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/LocalMachine12568 /user:####### /pass:#######
mstsc /v:"LocalMachine12568"
Start-Sleep -s 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change a reg key to temporarily remove the security banner. Which one that is, I can tell you when I get to work :) I need to do a similar thing on the lab pcs at work, but I have a batch script for this ( shouldn't be to hard to convert to PS)

(Tried to only add this as a comment but couldn't)

So here's the registry keys that I disable, which disables the company EULA/license agreement/whatever you want to call it

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v "legalnoticecaption" /t REG_SZ /f ""
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v "legalnoticetext" /t REG_SZ /f ""
```

You can add them remotely with powershell http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/03/16/use-powershell-to-edit-the-registry-on-remote-computers.aspx

Or, the way I do it is remotely executing a batch script with `psexec`. So copy the 2 batch files to the remote pc and run the one you want

Enable_autologin.bat

```
@echo off

set SOURCE=%~dp0

REM --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM Enable "Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon" in group policy
REM --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM reg add "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v SyncForegroundPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

REM --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM Disable Legal Notice
REM --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v "legalnoticecaption" /t REG_SZ /f ""
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v "legalnoticetext" /t REG_SZ /f ""

REM --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM Enable Auto login
REM --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "AutoAdminLogon" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "DefaultDomainName" /t REG_SZ /d "%COMPUTERNAME%" /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "DefaultUserName" /t REG_SZ /d "<user>" /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "DefaultPassword" /t REG_SZ /d "<password>" /f
```

Disable_autologin.bat

```
@echo off

set SOURCE=%~dp0

REM --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM Disable Auto login
REM --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "AutoAdminLogon" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "DefaultDomainName" /t REG_SZ /f ""
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "DefaultUserName" /t REG_SZ /f ""
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "DefaultPassword" /t REG_SZ /f ""
```

If Group Policy is set up for it, it will automattically set the EULA banner back after the next `gpupdate`